# Spring webflow model binding in form: Weird behaviour of autofilling of field values or vanishing of field values

Tags: forms, spring, jsp, spring-webflow-2

I want to bind my model to my jsp form within a flow. I am getting sorts of a weird behaviour.

In my search jsp I have this form:

```
<form:form method = "post" modelAttribute = "item">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Code:</td>
<td><form:input path="code" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><form:input path="name" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>description:</td>
<td><form:input path="description" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>center:</td>
<td><form:input path="center" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Organisation</td>
<td><form:input path="organisation" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Division</td>
<td><form:input path="division" />  </td>
</tr>
</table>   
<br />
<input type="submit" name="_eventId_send" value="Send" />
<input type="submit" name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancel" />
```

The model binded to the form is so far just a class with mere private String properties and their getters/setters.

In my flow XML I have simply:

```
<view-state id="Search" view="/Search" model="item">
  <binder>
        <binding property="code" />        
        <binding property="name" required="true" />         
        <binding property="description" />
        <binding property="center" />
        <binding property="organisation" />
        <binding property="division" />
    </binder>
    <transition on="send" to="temp" />
<transition on="cancel" to="SubEnd" />
</view-state>
```

No logic behind the data so far, it's just to transit to the next view when name is entered and stay in the current one when not.

What I've done is to enter something into all field except name and press the send button. I would expect that I would remain on the current page (what happens) and all fields will keep their values, but weirdly enough the field for description gets emptied. I looked at the post/get and the whole form gets a post but in the get response the value for description is not returned from the server. (When I change the order of the elements in the form, it's still just "description" that gets emptied.) In some seldom cases when I not fill out all except name but only a few, the field values would even swap their places.

What is going wrong here?

EDIT: Found it: eclipse was not working all too properly, but had too much open so I didn't restart and instead of using getter/setter generation I did some copy and paste. Instead of returning the description property in the getter method somehow name was returned, which caused the bug.

Comment: Show the class for item. Also do you have a validator? If yes show it as well.